# Windows Communication Foundation in VS 2008

Tags: wcf

What are the benefits of creating a WCF Service Library rather than creating the tradiational web service application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, I don't think you're limited to only http-based bindings.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a service library, you separate the service logic from the hosting. You can then host this library in IIS or in a custom program of your own.

If you use the web service application template, you will have everything in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "traditional web service application", are you referring to an ASMX web service? If so, then the main benefit of the WCF Service Library is that it is using WCF.

The ASMX web service technology is pretty much out of steam, and has been replaced by WCF.